# Expediting eigenvalue solve in Eigen

Tags: eigen

I am solving for eigenvalues of relatively small NxN matrices (less than 50 in dimension), and am wondering whether I am doing something foolish in my benchmarks, Eigen's eigenvalue solver seems fairly slow.  Here is the driver function:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd eigs_speed_test(std::vector<std::size_t> &Nvec, std::size_t Nrepeats) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd results(Nvec.size(), 3);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Nvec.size(); ++i)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(Nvec[i], Nvec[i]);
        double maxeig;
        auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < Nrepeats; ++i) {
                maxeig = A.eigenvalues().real().minCoeff();
            }
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto elap_us = std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count()/Nrepeats*1e6;
        results.row(i) << Nvec[i], elap_us, maxeig;
    }
    return results;
}
```

I called it from a tiny pybind11 wrapped module in python.  It shows that relatively small matrices require a surprisingly large amount of time to find the eigenvalues:

```
N  average time to find eigenvalues (microseconds)
2  2.9026
4  8.1132
8  25.3879
16  91.3992
32  511.4046
```

Yes, I know it all depends on the architecture, but this is on a one-year-old Mac Mini, and I see similar numbers on other machines.  I would be curious whether others see similar behavior.

I am especially surprised that it takes 2 microseconds to find the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix, shouldn't that be at least a few orders of magnitude faster?  Compiled in release mode (`-O2` I believe)

**UPDATE**

I ran the same test on a ubuntu virtualbox running on an i7, and obtained similar results to @ggael.  Tried both with and without LAPACKE.

speed_test.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include "Eigen/Dense"

Eigen::MatrixXd eigs_speed_test(std::vector<std::size_t> &Nvec, std::size_t Nrepeats) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd results(Nvec.size(), 3);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Nvec.size(); ++i)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(Nvec[i], Nvec[i]);
        double maxeig;
        auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < Nrepeats; ++i) {
                maxeig = A.eigenvalues().real().minCoeff();
            }
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto elap_us = std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count()/Nrepeats*1e6;
        results.row(i) << Nvec[i], elap_us, maxeig;
    }
    return results;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<std::size_t> NxN;
    for (std::size_t i=2; i < 64; i *= 2){
        NxN.push_back(i);
    }
    Eigen::MatrixXd res = eigs_speed_test(NxN, 10000);
    for (std::size_t i =0; i < res.rows(); ++i){
        std::cout << res(i,0) << ": " << res(i,1) << " us\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

for which I get the results

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~/eigs_testing$ clang++ speed_test.cpp -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -std=c++11 -Iexternals/Eigen -DEIGEN_USE_LAPACKE -llapacke -o out_LAPACKE
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~/eigs_testing$ clang++ speed_test.cpp -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -std=c++11 -Iexternals/Eigen -o out_Eigen
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~/eigs_testing$ ./out_LAPACKE && ./out_Eigen
2: 1.54799 us
4: 4.93369 us
8: 13.225 us
16: 51.7491 us
32: 260.19 us
2: 0.637694 us
4: 4.1682 us
8: 12.6636 us
16: 56.1858 us
32: 265.023 us
```

Answer (score 3):

Your benchmark is for non-symmetric matrices, but in case your real problem is symmetric, then better use `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` which is much faster, and provide explicit routines for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices. Nonetheless, here are the performance I get with Eigen 3.3, `clang -O3 -march=native` on an i7:

```
2   -> 0.44479µs
4   -> 4.65588µs
8   -> 20.4203µs
16  -> 79.6082µs
32  -> 440.319µs
64  -> 2455.39µs
128 -> 22890.3µs
```

And with MKL sequential:

```
2   -> 1.64614µs
4   -> 6.21343µs
8   -> 20.4486µs
16  -> 72.9411µs
32  -> 375.88µs
64  -> 2124.27µs
128 -> 12342.9µs
```

So you can see that for small matrices Eigen exhibits smaller overhead. In contrast, Eigen's implementation of `EigenSolver` does not scale well with increasing matrix sizes. Note that this behavior is specific to `EigenSolver`, some other built-in matrix decompositions scale well (e.g., LU, LLT, QR, BDCSVD, etc.)

Comment: Sadly, the matrices are not symmetric - actually they are companion matrices for Chebyshev expansions.  It's quite surprising to me how slow the eigenvalue solvers are for such small matrices.

Answer (score 1):

`Eigen::MatrixXd`'s `eigenvalues().real()` calls numerical libraries (one of lapack)' function, probably `geev` or its sibling functions.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521147

A runtime you measured consists of various internal operations, including overhead of calling external libraries (eigen) and external-external libraries (lapack). Typically, such an overhead is constant number. For bigger matrix, overhead is negligible; like 2us of few hundreds seconds. For small matrix, overhead dominates runtime, and that's what you see. Depending on machine, it could be 2us; 1us; who knows.

If your problem is always big enough, ignore overhead and spend your time and computation time on solving other issues.

If your problem is always small and even 2us overhead must be eliminated, you have following options:

1. Implement yourself. You can write single line code for 2x2 case.
2. Try use sized Eigen container `Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>`, e.g. `Eigen::Matrix2d`. It is a template container and lirbary/compiler will try to find optimized/inlined scenarios for each size. Tho, I dont think Eigen implemented lapack operations; Eigen probably has implemented some of blas operations.
3. Try use different backend. There are lots of lapack options and you can find something with low overhead.
4. Try lower overhead. You may try some linker options to reduce dynamic dispatch overhead.

Also, release mode -O2 does not matter much, as you are calling already compiled lapack.

Comment: Actually, I think your first point is incorrect. Eigen doesn't delegate to LAPACK and friends unless you defined EIGEN_USE_LAPACK.  Otherwise it uses its own internal routines.

Comment: ibell is right, though to me more precise, the macro is spelled `EIGEN_USE_LAPACKE` because it uses the LAPACKE C interface.